# Json Parsing using Ajax in Javascript to count number of occurrences when equal to a certain value

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, parsing

I cant seem to get my head round what is the most efficient way to parse this. So my problem is to find in all of the "source" fields if they contain text that is equal to say iPhone or ipad to add them to counter variables respectfully. Similar in the "entities" if they contain no values add to a counter variable in javascript. I respect if this may be a duplicate but I struggled to find a similar solution to my problem. Thanks to anyone that takes their time to help out.

Sample of My JSON local file

```
[{"id":"714249552807792640","user":"David Villa",
"text":"||: If only there were actually Football fakes who spoke English rather than Spanish or German I would so bring this back\ud83d\ude4f\ud83c\udffb",
"url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/David Villa\/status\/714249552807792640",
"source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>",
"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":[],"urls":[]},
"verified":false,
"user_mentions":false,
"sentiment":"negative"}
```

My Javascript file which I would call

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    data: {get_param: 'value'},
    url: 'data.json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, element){


        })   


    },      
})
```

Comment: Have you looked at the includes method on the String object?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: @Brian Yes Thanks but how do I apply to the JSON object, would it be like this 

iPhoneCount==0;
               if (element.sources.includes('iPhone')){
                   iPhoneCount++;
               }

Comment: Sounds about right.  However you would have to instantiate your counter variable with just one '=' as '==' is checking for equality and provides a true or false value.